# Remove all type of special characters in unix .csv file

Tags: escape-characters, special-characters

I am processing a huge stream of CSV data coming from a source which includes special characters, such as the following:

```
`÷ Þ Ÿ ³ Ù ÷`
```

Here is an example row from a data set which includes these characters:

```
'÷ÞW' , 'ŸŸŸŸŸŸŸ', '³ŸŸÙ÷'
```

Here is another example taken from a different data set:

```
WCP16,2013-06-04 20:06:24,2013-06-04,CPU,PrimeNumberGenerationTest,PASS,USA,H‌​F0SXV1,,,N,9999
WCP06,2013-06-04 20:06:24,2013-06-04,CPU,RegisterTest,PASS,USA,HF0SXV1,,,N,99‌​99
WCD42,2013-06-04 20:06:24,2013-06-04,DVDMINUSRW,MainICTest,PASS,USA,HF0SXV1,,‌​,N,9999
WCP09,2013-06-05 01:52:53,2013-06-05,CPU,SSE3Test,PASS,,?÷ÞQ»,,,N,9999
WCP10,2013-06-05 01:52:53,2013-06-05,CPU,SSE4_1Test,PASS,,?÷ÞQ»,,,N,9999
```

If I knew what type of characters to expect then I could handle that in [Informatica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informatica) when I the read file.

But in my situation I am not sure what type of data I will get on any given day, and as a result my jobs are failing. So I need a way to remove all special characters from the data.

Comment: source data with , separator                                                                                                   WCP16,2013-06-04 20:06:24,2013-06-04,CPU,PrimeNumberGenerationTest,PASS,USA,HF0SXV1,,,N,9999
WCP06,2013-06-04 20:06:24,2013-06-04,CPU,RegisterTest,PASS,USA,HF0SXV1,,,N,9999
WCD42,2013-06-04 20:06:24,2013-06-04,DVDMINUSRW,MainICTest,PASS,USA,HF0SXV1,,,N,9999
WCP09,2013-06-05 01:52:53,2013-06-05,CPU,SSE3Test,PASS,,?÷ÞQ»,,,N,9999
WCP10,2013-06-05 01:52:53,2013-06-05,CPU,SSE4_1Test,PASS,,?÷ÞQ»,,,N,9999

Comment: move your data into the question and format it properly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "special characters", so I'm going to assume that you want to get rid of non-[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters. There are a few different tools that might work for you. The first few that come to mind for me are:

1. `iconv` (internationalization conversion)
2. `tr` (translate)
3. `sed` (stream editor)

#### `iconv` (internationalization conversion)

Here is a solution using [iconv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv):

```
iconv -c -f utf-8 -t ascii input_file.csv
```

The `-f` flag (*from*) specifies an input format, the `-t` flag (*to*) specifies an output format, and the `-c` flag tells `iconv` to discard characters that cannot be converted to the target. This writes the results to standard output (i.e. to your console). If you want to write the results to a new file you would do something like this instead:

```
iconv -c -f utf-8 -t ascii input_file.csv -o output_file.csv
```

Then, if you want, you can replace the original file with the new file:

```
mv -i output_file.csv input_file.csv
```

Here is how `iconv` handles your first example string:

```
$ echo "'÷ÞW' , 'ŸŸŸŸŸŸŸ', '³ŸŸÙ÷'" | iconv -c -f utf8 -t ascii
'W' , '', ''
```

#### `tr` (translate)

Here is a solution using the [tr (translate)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_(Unix)) command:

```
cat input_file.csv | tr -cd '\000-\177'
```

The `\000-\177` pattern specifies the numerical range 0-127 using [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) notation. This is the range of values for ASCII characters. The `-c` flag tells `tr` to match values in the complement of this range (i.e. to match non-ASCII characters) and the `-d` flag tells `tr` perform deletion (instead of translation).

To write the results to a file you would use [output redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html):

```
cat input_file.csv | tr -cd '\000-\177' > output_file.csv
```

Here is how `tr` handles your first example string:

```
$ echo "'÷ÞW' , 'ŸŸŸŸŸŸŸ', '³ŸŸÙ÷'" | tr -cd '\000-\177'
'W' , '', ''
```

#### `sed` (stream editor)

Here is a solution using [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed):

```
sed 's/[\d128-\d255]//g' input_file.csv
```

The `s` prefix tells `sed` to perform substitution, the `g` suffix tells `sed` to match patterns globally (by default only the first occurrence is matched), the pattern `[\d128-\d255]` tells `sed` to match characters with decimal values in the range 128-255 (i.e. non-ASCII characters), and the empty string between the second and third forward-slashes tells `sed` to replace matched patterns with the empty string (i.e. to remove them).

Unlike many other programs, `sed` has an option to update the file in-place (instead of manually writing to a different file and then replacing the original):

```
sed -i 's/[\d128-\d255]//g' input_file.csv
```

Here is how `sed` handles your first example string:

```
$ echo "'÷ÞW' , 'ŸŸŸŸŸŸŸ', '³ŸŸÙ÷'" | sed 's/[\d128-\d255]//g'
'W' , '', ''
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation it will help me in feature problems

Comment: for now i used this sed -e 's/[^a-zA-Z*0-9*,*:*-]/ /g;s/  */ /g' mydell.csv > mydell_new.csv
i got the expected result

Comment: As [zino](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/291319/zino) pointed out in an “answer” that wasn’t an answer (which should have been a comment, and which has probably been deleted by now), ``s/[\d128-\d255]//`` does not work in `sed`.

Comment: @Scott It seems to be working for me. The snippet I included in my response was basically a copy-paste from my shell session.

Comment: Well, I’m having a bad brain day; my head hurts. (1) I don’t recall knowing about ``\d `` *`nnn`*, and I had trouble finding documentation on it.  (The only place I found was [the GNU ‘sed’ manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt) — it isn’t in the man page.  Can you tell me where else it’s documented that I should have found and/or known about?)  (2) It works in `sed` version 4.2.2 — up through ``d127``.  It chokes on higher values (``\d128`` and above) in `[`…`]` ranges. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … What’s really weird is that it gives an error message if used in a range (e.g., ``[Z-\d159]``) but fails silently if used in a list (e.g., ``[Z\d159]``).  (3) I have two different copies of ``sed`` that both claim to be version 4.2.2.  They both support ``\d `` *`nnn`*, but the one on Cygwin has problems with it that I haven’t fully diagnosed yet.

Comment: @Scott I searched for the string [sed \dXXX](https://www.google.com/search?q=sed+%5CdXXX) and found some other references (e.g. [The Sed WikiBook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Sed)), but nothing more authoritative than the GNU Sed Manual, which you've already found. I haven't looked into any non-GNU versions of `sed` and as far as Cygwin goes... yeah, I'm not going to touch that - I only have very limited experience there.